# Django Cannot get media images or files

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

`Django 2.0.2` cannot get the images or cannot show the images in media directory, also I defined them both media and static url and directory in `setting.py`. I don't know how to write the `views.py`

Here is the error I am getting:

> (""GET /media/Cover_jDKCLdR.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4542")

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
if DEBUG:
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
  STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
  MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
  STATICFILES_DIRS=[
  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
  ]
```

make above changes in `setting.py` to get static files and media files for your Django project

**Static** files for storing JS and css files.

**media** files for storing images

**Staticonly** for storing cache files which will create and stored here automatically when you run `collectstatic`

**To load image inside the template**

`<img src="/media/wwww.jpg" class="img-responsive"`

**if you still getting confused to make this comment here i will try to help you and you can do these by following this** [click here!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wbfk16jEOk)